# How to preserve other application windows sizes and positions when changing resolution? (eg. to and from full screen game in non-desktop resolution)

Tags: windows, opengl, direct3d

Has anyone noticed this odd behavior of application that utilize D3D or OpenGL when they go to full screen in Windows? It applies only when applications go to full screen and then switch back to window or terminate. They either shuffle window positions of other applications (when I am on single monitor machine), or move all the other applications windows to another screen when I am on multiple monitor machine.

I would take this for granted if there weren't for applications that didn't show this two anomalies. So, my question would be what exactly does one need to take care of when writing an application to alleviate these two problems? Also, I am not sure if this problem exists on other platforms besides Windows?

My primary setup concerning this is OpenGL/C++, but I presume this applies to whatever setup you have since it seems to be platform API thing that needs to be taken care of.

---

**edit**: OK, here is some more clarification on my observation. Problem persists even on same resolution as desktop one. So, it does not seem to be related to resolution switch, because I've seen application/games that even when they are not in the same resolution as desktop, when they switch back, windows on desktop are restored as they once were before the full screen application was run.

---

**edit2**: it looks like it is a resolution switch problem, Windows (at least XP) does not seem to remember positions and size (in case of multiple monitor setup) of applications windows. Looks like only solution is the one I provided in an answer to the question - even though it seems like something OS should provide, at least as an API call or two. I'm still not convinced this is the only solution, there must be an easy way of graceful, easy restoration, no?

Comment: Because they changed the resolution?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be using `ChangedDisplaySettingsEx(..., CDS_FULLSCREEN, NULL)`? That will tell the system the resolution swap is temporary.

Comment: Using CDS_FULLSCREEN is the correct way to handle this. With it the positions and sizes of other windows won't change and the system will even restore the original display mode automatically when the process exits.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that I'm 100% certain about the situation you're experiencing.  However, my guess is it's because most D3D/OpenGL games will change the resolution of your machine when they startup/shutdown for performance reasons.

The ones you see that don't shuffle the windows around are likely not changing the resolution because they may be able to run at your current settings.

Comment: ok, I've added more clarification to the question. It does not seem to be resolution related but more to the "remembering" of desktop/windows sizes and positions before and after restoration.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I've gone through some more research about this - it looks like there is no default fallback on restoring all running windows sizes and positions after changing resolution, so it must be done from within an application (at least in XP).

So, in order to gracefully return back from other resolution (full screen game for example), I would need to get all running applications hWnd's with EnumWindows and appropriate callback and store each of the windows RECT structure via GetWindowRect in a list.

When switching back to desktop resolution I would EnumWindows again, but with a different callback which sets each of the running application windows position and size with SetWindowPos, using the list of RECTs I've saved before switching to full screen.

There are gotcha's, ofcourse, like watching you get a window hwnd only through EnumWindows etc. It seems odd that OS doesn't provide a feature like that, even if only API. I wonder how other OS's out there handle this, if they handle it at all.